# Issue with connecting to WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I am learning WCF and having some trouble accessing the service after hosting it. I created a WCF Service which has following entries in Web.config -

**Service Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now, As I wanted to host this service, I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx) tutorial and created a console application responsible for hosting this service. This is the App.config for host -

**Host App.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>    
<services>
  <service name="ServiceName"
           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceNameBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:59918/ServiceName.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="ServiceName.IServiceName" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceNameBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I ran the host and installed the service. I can now start/stop the service from services.msc and also able to add the reference correctly to the client. The issue is that when I call any service method, the client is not able to connect to it and simply times out. Why is this happening? Are the Web.config and App.config correct here?

Note: I am also dealing with large amount of data being passed in and out of the service. That is why I have set maxRecievedMessageSize param.

Comment: You haven't changed the timeouts. Most likely it takes longer than the allowed time to transmit the message. Test with less data to verify the service and client actually work. Then find out what timeouts you need.

Comment: I have tested the service without hosting and including in the same project. There haven't been any issues. It takes less than 2 sec to return data.

Comment: If you are hosting it in console application then web.config is redundant. Also if you intend to use wsHttpBinding then your service base address URL scheme should be https and not http.

Comment: You also need to allow your service to listen on `http://localhost:59918/` using `netsh`. Your ServiceHost throws an exception, search the web for that and you'll find out how to do that. It also helps yo include all relevant details, such as those from your previous comment and the actual exception of the client, in your question.

Comment: @PankajKapare Should I also set maxRecievedMessageSize settings in App.config?

Comment: It depends. If your request is going to be bigger than 65,536 bytes then you may need to change maxRecievedMessageSize  else you can live with default value i.e. 65,536 bytes

Comment: Have you tried connecting with an external tool like SoapUI?

Comment: @Codor No, I haven't. How does it help?

Comment: It was just an idea for narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Still struggling to get this working. I had to temporarily create a web app to host the service. Can anyone redirect me to useful links that can help me in hosting wcf services in windows?